# Check if a member is referenced within the solution in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, reference

I know that VisualStudio has the possibilty to check whether a member is used ("See all references").

Is it possible to check this programmatically as well. Like:

```
 Assembly assem = Assembly.GetAssembly(t);
 MemberInfo[] members = t.GetMembers();
 foreach (MemberInfo mi in members)
        {
           // Check if member is used somewhere in the solution                

        }
```

Comment: There could be a way using Roslyn ... but don't ask me how ...

Comment: I've closed it as a duplicate. Roslyn is used for static analysis. If you wanted to do runtime analysis instead (i.e. with reflection), let me know and I'll re-open.